# How to translate svg code to javascript code?

Tags: javascript, svg

I learned here stackoverflow that you can dynamically insert svg element into an HTML file as follows.

```
  var svgnode = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg'); 
  var path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','path');
  path .setAttribute("d","......");
  svgnode.appendChild(path);
  document...........appendChild(svgnode);
```

And it works well.
I expected that you can continue it as follows too.

```
var defs = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','defs');
var use = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','use');
var path2=document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','path');
path2.setAttribute("d","....");
path2.setAttribute("id","path2");
defs.appendChild(path2);
use.setAttribute("xlink:href","#path2");
use.setAttribute("x","10");
use.setAttribute("y","10");
svgnode.appendChild(defs);
svgnode.appendChild(use);
document...........appendChild(svgnode);
```

But the second one just fails .

Please point out what is wrong in the second one.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where does it fail?  What error message or symptom are you seeing?

Comment: In Google Chrome,the resultant new page  holds correct svg but it does not show the picture. Though saving it in a file and opening the saved file shows the correct picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the `xlink:href` that's the problem and that needs to be in the xlink namespace:

```
use.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", "#path2");
```

The rest of the code will work fine in the non-namespaced form.